# How to close iframe using 'end chat' button?

Tags: liveagent, button, iframe, chat

I have placed the Live Chat into an iFrame and the chat functionality works.
Unfortunately, when I click the 'cancel chat' button, the chat ends, but the iFrame is still visible.

Is there a way to make 'cancel chat' button close the iFrame, as it does when the chat is in a pop up?

Comment: Can you write onlclick event in your button to close popup like `onclick="window.close()"`?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, as the  Live Agent chat window with the 'Cancle chat button'  is delivered by SalesForce.

Comment: Oh that sucks !

Answer (score -1):

"Closing" the current iFrame is not possible but you can tell the parent to manipulate the dom and make it invisible.

In IFrame:

```
parent.closeIFrame(); //Call this method onclick on Close Chat button
```

In parent:

```
function closeIFrame(){
     $('#youriframeid').remove();
 }
```